# vector size creating issue in for loop

Tags: c++, vector

I created a vector of type int and explicitly declared a size of 3 for the vector. The for loop is suppose to be looping until x is equal or greater than 3. Unfortunately, the for loop keeps running pass 3. Can anyone elaborate as to why this is occurring? I'm going to take a stab at it and say it's "u.size" that's creating the issue, but why would it be if I declared a size for the vector?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> u (3);

    for(size_t x = 0; x < u.size();x++)
    {
        int g = x;
        u.push_back(g);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push_back` *appends* an element at the end of the vector, so its size is constantly expanding. The exit condition for the `for` loop is evaluated at each iteration, so your loop will never terminate, because your vector grows of 1 element at each iteration.

Either you do:

```
vector<int> u;
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    u.push_back(i);
```

allowing the vector to expand by itself, or create the vector of the correct size from the beginning, and store the elements in their corresponding position:

```
vector<int> u(3);
for(size_t i=0; i<u.size(); ++i)
    u[i]=i;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are constantly calling `push_back`, changing the `size`.

If your intention is to fill a vector like this, you can simply do the following:

```
vector<int> u;
for(size_t x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    u.push_back(x);
}
```

Or, alternately,

```
vector<int> u(3); // the constructor fills the vector with 3 default-initialized elements
for(size_t x = 0; x < u.size(); x++) {
    u[x] = x;
}
```

Comment: There's also std::iota.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, you are increasing the size of the vector. 
The best way to fill the container for your needs would probably be by using `std::iota` in `<numeric>`. 
Working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> u(3);
    iota(u.begin(), u.end(), 0); // Start with value 0

    return 0;
}
```